# Is there any way to apply Fluent Validation for a group of similar properties in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluentvalidation

I got a ViewModel (MovieNamesModel) as given below:

```
{
  public string? MovieName1 { get; set; }
  public string? MovieName2 { get; set; }
  public string? MovieName3 { get; set; }
  ...
  ...
  public string? MovieName15 { get; set; }

  public DateTime MovieDate1 { get; set; }
  public DateTime MovieDate2 { get; set; }
  public DateTime MovieDate3 { get; set; }
  ...
  ...
  public DateTime MovieDate10 { get; set; }
}
```

I need to implement validation on this ViewModel. Initially, I thought of using Data Annotations for the same. Now, implementing DateTime validation (Range of Dates), using Data Annotations would be critical.

Then I came to know about Fluent Validation and thought of keeping all the validations in a single place.

The validations for all the MovieName fields will be the same and so is for MovieDate fields.

So, I want to implement same RuleFor<> for a bunch of similar properties and Error Message also would need to write down once.

Something like as given below:

```
RuleFor(x => new { MovieName1, MovieName2, MovieName3, ..., MovieName15 })
    .MaximumLength(50)
    .WithMessage("MovieName<how to get the respective Movie Number here> can be of max 50 characters.");

-- The same am looking for Date Range Validation --
```

So, this will apply the same rule for a bunch of properties of similar types. I don't have to write/modify the error messages for all the fields again and again.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ValidationRule` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Sidenote:
Instead of duplicating the name and date of the movies, you could add a class `Movie` with a `Name` and `Date` property. Then add the validation in the setter of each property (and in the constructor).
Now you could use a `ObservableCollection<Movie>` in your ViewModel and use a ListView or something similar in combination with datatemplates for displaying your movies. For example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/observablecollection-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/Karnah/ReactiveValidation for validating MVVM properties. It looks quite similar to FluentValidation, but has built-in `INotifyPropertyChanged` support.
You can use like it:

```
builder
    .RuleFor(vm => Name, vm => vm.Surname)
    .NotNull()
    .SetValidator(new MaxLengthValidator<BaseSampleViewModel>(_ => 16, ValidationMessageType.Error));
```

Unfortunately, you have to use SetValidator in this case, because builder use `object` as base type for combined properties. But I'll fix it in a future.

Also, this library has different methods for collections and complex properties, if you'll want to combine it.